# Difference between two (not consecutive) primes

Tags: prime-numbers, prime-gaps

I am searching for an lower bound on the difference between the $(n+k)$-th and $n$-th prime number in terms of $k$. I have something like this in mind (conjecture):

> Let $(p_k)_k$ denote the sequence of primes (i.e. $p_1 = 2, p_2 = 3, p_3 = 5, \dotsc$). Then there exists a constant $c > 0$, such that $p_{n+k} - p_n \ge c \cdot p_k$ for all $n,k \in \mathbb{N}$.

or alternatively

> Let $(p_k)_k$ denote the sequence of primes (i.e. $p_1 = 2, p_2 = 3, p_3 = 5, \dotsc$). Then there exists a constant $c > 0$, such that $p_{n+k} - p_n \ge c\cdot ( k \cdot \log k)$ for all $n,k \in \mathbb{N}$.

Having the prime number theorem, more precisely $p_n \sim n \log n$, in mind, this seems to be true... I appreciate any hint.

Comment: Have you tried looking at this Wolfram MathWorld [link](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimeGaps.html) on Prime Gaps?

Comment: I haven't. Now I have, but I don't see any hint useful for my problem.

Comment: If $p_n = c \cdot p_k$ or $c\cdot ( k \cdot \log k)$ and then have $n = n - k$ then you have $p_{n} / 2 < p_{n-k}$. This is Srinivasan's Lemma if n is as stated below, see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan_prime#Ramanujan_prime_corollary

Comment: Now, if you take that Lemma and look at the next primes, you have the Ramanujan prime corollary: $2p_{i-n} > p_i$ for $i>k$ where $k=\pi(p_k)=\pi(R_n)$

Comment: I feel like this question deserves more attention